# (1+1)D General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

What is the interest of studying the (1+1)dimension General Relativity?

Comment: You can have a look at "Aspects of General Relativity in 1+1 Dimensions" by Mellinger, 2012. Einstein equations are just algebraic equations and the Ricci tensor and scalar are both zero. Another reference is: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/29/2/013 " In this paper, we show that by working in (1+1) dimensions one can construct a toy model of gravity that is much simpler than general relativity, yet retains much of its conceptual structure. The model is a useful pedagogical tool because it illustrates many of the ideas of general relativity in a simplified context".

Comment: related: BH in 1+1 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604208/226902